Помогите расставить знаки препинания?
Начинал оператором(?) и вот уже 10 лет(?) как работает в нашей компании.

Начинал оператором, и вот уже 20  лет, как.. Вообще-то обычно мы не выполняем за других задания.

А мы - это кто?

Участники сайта: те, кто отвечает на вопросы.

Я тоже отвечаю на вопросы иногда и задание выполню, если понадобится. Так что вы не правы.

Правильно:
Начинал оператором, и вот уже (прошло) 10 лет, как работает в нашей компании.
Пояснение

Вторая часть — это сложное предложение (СПП), запятая ставится. В главной части  подразумевались слова прошло с того времени или прошло с того момента.

Сравнить: Десятый год как он здесь работает.


Это простое предложение, союз КАК можно убрать, запятой нет.
Розенталь, § 33. Запятая между главной и придаточной частями сложноподчиненного предложения, пункт 2
2. В составе сложноподчиненного предложения могут быть 
неполные предложения:
1) неполное предложение в качестве главной части: Вот уже 
два года, как мы женаты (ср.: Мы женаты вот уже два года — 
простое предложение); Уже месяц, как он вернулся с юга (ср.: 
Он уже месяц как вернулся с юга — запятая перед союзом как 
«оторвала» бы сказуемое от подлежащего); Уже три недели, как 
мы здесь (ср.: Мы уже три недели как здесь — обстоятельство 
места выражено сочетанием как здесь).

Но: Третий день как он здесь — простое предложение, тогда 
как в приведенных выше примерах в главной части предложения 
подразумевались слова прошло с того времени или прошло с 
того момента;

